# API Platform - Entity Translation, Doctrine Translatable

Tags: doctrine-extensions, api-platform.com

I'm trying to add [KnpLabs Doctrine Behaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) -  and precisely, the [Translatable Behavior](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable) - on one of the entity in my API Platform project.

Here's what I've done so far :

```
    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
    use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

    /**
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
    * @ApiResource
    */
    class Article
    {
        use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation,
            ORMBehaviors\Timestampable\Timestampable
        ;

        /**
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return int
         */
         public function getId()
         {
             return $this->id;
         }
    }
```

And here's the Entity translation :

```
    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
    use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
    use App\Traits as CustomTraits;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleTranslationRepository")
     * @ApiResource
     */
     class ArticleTranslation
     {
          use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

          /**
           * @var string
           * 
           * @ORM\Column(name="someFieldToTranslate", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
           */
           private $someFieldToTranslate;

           public function getSomeFieldToTranslate(){...}
           public function setSomeFieldToTranslate($someFieldToTranslate){...}
     }
```

Here's the basic "configuration" for getting Translatable Behavior working according to the doc.

Issues start when I try to update the DB schema : I got this error:

> No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\ArticleTranslation". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key in . (which is being imported from "/Sites/bookshop-api/config/routes/api_platform.yaml"). Make sure there is a
>     loader supporting the "api_platform" type.

However in Translatable Traits, there's already an ID and documentation precise that Translation Entity should only have fields we want to translate...

Anyway, I've put an ID to this ArtcleTranslation Entity to get rid of the error  :

```
    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
    use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
    use App\Traits as CustomTraits;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleTranslationRepository")
     * @ApiResource
     */
     class ArticleTranslation
     {
          use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

          /**
           * @ORM\Id
           * @ORM\GeneratedValue
           * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
           */
           protected $id;


          /**
           * @var string
           * 
           * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
           */
           private $content;

           public function getContent(){...}
           public function setContent($someContent){...}
     }
```

From here, no error when I update the DB schema. Perfect ! 
Now I can take a look at the Swagger Documentation :

[image]

Everything looks fine ! But when I do take a look at the DB :

In Article table :

- no "local" field
- no "empty" field

In ArticleTranslation table :

- no "translatable_id" field
- no "currentLocal"
- no "defaultLocal"

I guess it must be linked but in the swagger POST Tab, the model is different too.

[image]
         *article_translation model*

I only tried /GET and /POST method on both entities, they're working (I can see it in DB) but no relation between the 2 of them.

I hope my post is not too long but I tried to be the more specific !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to find the solution? Im facing the same problem. Thanks for any help

Comment: @Tahir still not found a solution..

Comment: In my case, subscriber was not registered in the bundle list. We need to register subscriber bundle as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#subscribers).
After fixing this, I got all columns in db.
Although im stuck at how can I send/get translations using default endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did another answer as the first question was to resolve a mistake and not to explain how I integrated Knp Labs Doctrine Translations with Api Platform.

Summary :

We have an entity `Article` which has some fields translated inside an `ArticleTranslation`. We want to retrieve the entity through `Api platform` with its translations and we want to add or update translations through the api.

What I did :

**1 -** `Article` entity has a `use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable`. If we look inside of this `trait`, it has 2 attributes : `$translations` and `$newTranslations`. We need to expose these attributes inside the `Article` entity :

```
class Article {
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    protected $translations;
    protected $newTranslations;
}
```

Now we have a new attribute `translations` which is automatically filled from `ArticleTranslation` when we are getting some `Article` from the `api`

**2 -** Now we want to add/edit some translations : We need to fill the `newTranslations` attribute inside the `Article` when we are sending to the api:

```
"newTranslations": {
    "en": {
      "description": "Firstname"
    },
    "fr": {
      "description": "Prénom"
    }
}
```

Now we are receiving the new translations into the api but it's not persisted because we have to call the function `mergeNewTranslations()`. This function just take all translations inside the attribute `$newTranslations` and merge it with the `$translations` attribute in order to persist it.

**3 -** I created a new `trait` that I called `TranslatableOverride`. I imported it on directly on my Entity next to `ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation`:

```
trait TranslatableOverride
{

    /**
     * Set collection of new translations.
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function setNewTranslations($newTranslations)
    {
        if ($newTranslations) {
            foreach ($newTranslations as $locale => $translations) {
                foreach ($translations as $key => $value) {
                    $tr = $this->translate($locale);
                    $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
                    if (method_exists($tr, $setter)) {
                        $tr->{$setter}($value);
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->mergeNewTranslations();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's pretty but it works like a charm with `api-platform`.

I didn't think about getting only one translation at a time. For the moment, I retrieve my entities with the whole bunch of translations which is definitely not efficient. I will add an override for the `getTranslations` in my override `trait` I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Maël for taking the time to answer this post, I'll try your solution when i can !

Comment: Hi, keep getting `"Could not denormalize object of type \"Knp\\DoctrineBehaviors\\Contract\\Entity\\TranslationInterface[]\", no supporting normalizer found."` when I try to persist newTranslations according to your answer. Would you have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a mistake. You have an entity `Article` which should be the `translatable` and you want to translate some fields which will be the `translations`?

So you should make the opposite, put the `use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable`on the `Article` and the `use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation` on the `ArticleTranslation`

The fix for your `Article` entity :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
* @ApiResource
*/
class Article
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable,
        ORMBehaviors\Timestampable\Timestampable
    ;

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
     public function getId()
     {
         return $this->id;
     }
}
```

and the fix for your `ArticleTranslation` entity :

```
    namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Traits as CustomTraits;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleTranslationRepository")
 * @ApiResource
 */
 class ArticleTranslation
 {
      use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

      /**
       * @var string
       * 
       * @ORM\Column(name="someFieldToTranslate", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
       */
       private $someFieldToTranslate;

       public function getSomeFieldToTranslate(){...}
       public function setSomeFieldToTranslate($someFieldToTranslate){...}
 }
```

Let me know if everything is alright now.

Comment: thanks for the reply! im in an another project now but i will take a look asap ! By the way, have u been able to use [knplabsBehaviour](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable)  with Api Platform ?

Comment: Yes it works. I've just a trouble on `POST` and `PUT`. I think the `newTranslations` field isn't process with api-platform. But I'm gonna find a solution/trick.

Comment: Have you found a solution with POST/PUT? Is there any other way to integrate Entity translation in ApiPlatform? I'm looking for solution where entity (e.g. Article) on GET will give either content with possibility to select translation via locale key or by passing locale and in response receive content in language specified by locale. Haven't found yet best solution :(

Comment: I made a new complete answer.